# Purpose of var a = b.c = function(){} syntax

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

I've lately browsed js code and the following syntax keeps coming up:

```
var foo = bar.bi = function() {...}
```

This is unfamiliar syntax to me. Is it only to define two names for the same function? If so, why not only define it as `bar.bi = function()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assigns the same value to the variable and the `bi` property of the `bar` object at the same time.

This way the object's property gets the value, but you can still reference it as a variable, which is likely a little faster.

Effectively the same as...

```
bar.bi = function() {...};
var foo = bar.bi;

foo === bar.bi; // true
```

---

Or you can visualize it as...

```
var foo = ( bar.bi = function() {...} );
```

So the assignment to `bar.bi` happens first. The result returned from the assignment expression is the same function, and that result is assigned to `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to assigning the function to 2 variable, the context also changes depending on how you call it.

```
bar.bi();
```

would have it's context as the `bar` object, as if you would have used this:

```
foo.call(bar);
```

But using it off the other variable, like this:

```
foo();
```

would use the context of `foo`. So if `foo` is in the global context, it'll be equivalent to this:

```
bar.bi.call(window);
```

Comment: @Fdr - I don't know. I haven't really seen it in action ever, but it's good to know.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a compound assignment

```
var r = x = 3;
```

assigns 3 to x, and also to r, which is newly declared.

Your example just substitutes a function in place of 3, and an object property—`bar.bi`—in place of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where it is used.

Both `foo`and `bar.bi` point to same function here. That means the function can be invoked using

```
foo();
```

and

```
bar.bi();
```

At the same time it differs in the value of `this` inside the function. To make the first one equal to second one, it should be invoked as given below

```
foo.call(bar);
```

or

```
foo.apply(bar);
```

This ensures that `this` will point to `bar` inside the function.

please refer:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply.

.

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = bar.bi = function() {...};



bar.bi === function() {...} //true

foo === bar.bi //true
```

bar will be an object who responds to method bi.

Comment: I think you'll find that your first two `===` comparisons will be `// false` because you're comparing two different function objects. Your last one is of course correct though.